# jQuery autocomplete not working with JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement the jQuery autocomplete. I feel like everything is set up just fine, however It's not working.

**SearchSkies method**

```
public JsonResult SearchSkies(string query)
{
     SkiDao skiDao = new SkiDao();
     IList<Ski> skies = skiDao.SearchSkies(query);    
     List<string> brands = (from Ski s in skies select s.Brand).ToList();
     return Json(brands, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**The script in View**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( function() {
    $( "#searchBox" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax( {
          url: '@Url.Action("SearchSkies","Skies")',
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            query: request.term
          },
          success: function (data) {
              response(data);
          }
        } );
      },
      minLength: 2,
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What is not working? What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: I am not getting any errors, the autocomplete just doesn't complete anything... @StephenMuecke

Comment: Are you getting brands from the server? You first need to debug the code and see if any items are returned from the server or not.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya seems like the method SearchSkies isn't called at any time when i debug it

Comment: `SearchSkies` action method should be HttpPost. And you need to make request accordingly from AJAX. http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Jquery-AutoComplete-TextBox-with-database-In-Asp-Net-MVC

Answer (score 0):

You are not mentioning type of request(GET/POST) in ajax call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
       $("#searchBox").autocomplete({  
           source: function(request,response) {  
               $.ajax({  
                   url: "/Skies/SearchSkies",  
                   type: "POST",    <<----
                   dataType: "json",  
                   data: { query: request.term },  
                   success: function (data) {  
                       response($.map(data, function (item) {  
                           return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name };  
                       }))      
                   }  
               })  
           },  
           messages: {  
               noResults: "", results: ""  
           }  
       });  
   })
```

And the controller

```
public class SkiesController : Controller  
{  
        // GET: Home  
        [HttpGet]  
        public ActionResult Index()  
        {  
            return View();  
        }  
        [HttpPost]  
        public JsonResult SearchSkies(string query)  
        {                
        SkiDao skiDao = new SkiDao();
        IList<Ski> skies = skiDao.SearchSkies(query);

        List<string> brands = (from Ski s in skies select s.Brand).ToList();
        return Json(brands, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }  
 }
```

Comment: Don't say vague statement like `same problem`,did you debug to see if the controller is getting hit,if not what is there in browser console.